# How do I search for a specific string and return the entire line containing that string?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have text file like this:

> 11/18/2012 test1
>
> 11/19/2012 test2
>
> 11/20/2012 test3
>
> 11/21/2012 test4
>
> 11/22/2012 test5
>
> 11/23/2012 test6
>
> 11/24/2012 test7
>
> 11/25/2012 test8

How do I search for the current date and return the entire line containing that date? For instance, if I run the program today, it should return

> 11/18/2012 test1

Code:

```
string searchKeyword = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in textLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
    {
        results.Add(line);
        listBox2.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? (Break it down into several steps, and let us know which one has caused you a problem.)

Comment: ok i made calendar event i made every thing but i wanna grab event from file and show it in current day only current day i try alot of code and i try this last one

 string searchKeyword = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
            string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in textLines)
{
if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
{
results.Add(line);
}
}
how i can save current event in list box

Comment: Edit this into your question, including what the result was. Is the real problem "transferring data into a list box" which is entirely separate to the file reading part?

Comment: i dont know if this work i have no result

Comment: Do not post your code in dropbox, post the relevent portions of your code here as a edit to your question.

Comment: ok i will remove all link :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*First* - split your text by lines. E.g. this way:

```
// string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

*Second* - find lines which start with current date string in specified format:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");    
IEnumerable<string> results = lines.Where(l => l.StartsWith(date));
```

If you completely sure that there could be only one such line, then use

```
string result = lines.SingleOrDefault(l => l.StartsWith(date));
```

---

Here is your code fixed and reafactored (you should use custom date string format and use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`)

```
string searchKeyword = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");

foreach (string line in textLines.Where(l => l.StartsWith(searchKeyword)))
    listBox2.Items.Add(line);
```

Comment: ok how i can show result by line in list box <3

Comment: @user1834172 don't use `string searchKeyword = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();` use custom formatting as I have provided: `string searchKeyword = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`. And use `.StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Comment: ok if i wanna change this code by your code how can do this?
in this private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @user1834172 see my previous comment - your code will work if you change it as I stated above

Comment: yaya work great <3 thx mate very much

Comment: @user1834172 see updated example (I also removed results list, because you can add strings to listbox directly)

Comment: ya i use it thx alot mate <3

Comment: @user1834172 then you can accept this answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = new List<string>();
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    if(line.StartsWith(currentDate))
        matches.Add(line);
}
```

To add them to the listbox:

```
foreach (var match in matches)
    listBox.Items.Add(match);
```

Comment: ok how i can show result by line in list box <3